# Covariance Matrix from 2D vectors - Tensorflow, Numpy

Tags: python, tensorflow, array-broadcasting

I'm trying to  generate a kernel function for GP using only Matrix operations (no loops).
Vectors where no problem taking advantage of broadcasting

```
def kernel(A,B):
    return 1/np.exp(np.linalg.norm(A-B.T))**2
```

A and B are both [n,1] vectors, but with [n,m] shaped matrices It just doesn't work. (Also tried reshaping to [1,n,m])
I'm interested on computing an X Matrix where every ij-th element is defined by Ai-Bj.

Now I'm working on Numpy but my final objective is implement this on Tensorflow.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is there any reason that you can't use np.cov?

Comment: Yes, the idea is to test different kernels and evaluate which one performs better, so the covariance function needs to be defined from scratch.